# C# merge pdf using Spire doesnt write content

Tags: c#, pdf

I have the following code to merge different documents and creates a pdf file.creates the files properly but doesn't show the document content on the created file. It looks like it creates the pages numbers but i cant see the documents content it just blank. What is missed here

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Filter = "All files (*.docx, *.pdf, *.pptx, *.pdf)| *.docx; *.pdf; *.pptx; *.xlsx";

            ofd.Multiselect = true;

            if (DialogResult.OK == ofd.ShowDialog())

            {

                string[] files = ofd.FileNames;

                listBoxFiles.Items.AddRange(files);

            }
        }
```

Here is document Merge code

```
 private void buttonMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Convert other file formats to PDF file
            string ext = string.Empty;
            foreach (object item in listBoxFiles.Items)
            {
                ext = Path.GetExtension(item.ToString());
                switch (ext)
                {
                    case ".docx":
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            Document doc = new Document(item.ToString());
                            doc.SaveToStream(ms, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.PDF);
                            PdfFiles.Add(new PdfDocument(ms));
                        }
                        break;
                    case ".pdf":
                        PdfFiles.Add(new PdfDocument(item.ToString()));
                        break;
                    case ".pptx":
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            Presentation ppt = new Presentation(item.ToString(), Spire.Presentation.FileFormat.Auto);
                            ppt.SaveToFile(ms, Spire.Presentation.FileFormat.PDF);
                            PdfFiles.Add(new PdfDocument(ms));
                        }
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx":
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            Workbook xls = new Workbook();
                            xls.LoadFromFile(item.ToString());
                            xls.SaveToStream(ms, Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
                            PdfFiles.Add(new PdfDocument(ms));
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            //Merge the PDF files into one PDF
            PdfDocument newPdf1 = new PdfDocument();
            foreach (PdfDocument doc in PdfFiles)
            {
                newPdf1.AppendPage(doc);
            }
            //Create a new PDF with specified page size, copy the content of merged file to new PDF file
            PdfDocument newPdf2 = new PdfDocument();
            foreach (PdfPageBase page in newPdf1.Pages)
            {
                PdfPageBase newPage = newPdf2.Pages.Add(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfMargins(0));
                PdfTextLayout loLayout = new PdfTextLayout();
                loLayout.Layout = PdfLayoutType.OnePage;
                page.CreateTemplate().Draw(newPage, new PointF(0, 0), loLayout);
            }
            //Save the destination PDF file
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Pdf files(*.pdf)|*.pdf";
            if (DialogResult.OK == sfd.ShowDialog())
            {
                newPdf2.SaveToFile(sfd.FileName);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the new merge method instead of the old one.
Check below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Spire.Doc;
using Spire.Pdf;
using Spire.Pdf.Graphics;
using Spire.Presentation;
using Spire.Xls;

namespace Merge_Office_Files_to_PDF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        ofd.Filter = "All files (*.docx, *.pdf, *.pptx, *.pdf)| *.docx; *.pdf; *.pptx; *.xlsx";

        ofd.Multiselect = true;

        if (DialogResult.OK == ofd.ShowDialog())
        {

            string[] files = ofd.FileNames;

            listBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string ext = string.Empty;
        List<Stream> filesStreams = new List<Stream>();
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream ms3 = new MemoryStream();
        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            ext = Path.GetExtension(item.ToString());
            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".docx":
                    Document doc = new Document(item.ToString());
                    doc.SaveToStream(ms1, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.PDF);
                    filesStreams.Add(ms1);

                    break;
                case ".pdf":
                    filesStreams.Add(File.OpenRead(item.ToString()));
                    break;
                case ".pptx":
                    Presentation ppt = new Presentation(item.ToString(), Spire.Presentation.FileFormat.Auto);
                    ppt.SaveToFile(ms2, Spire.Presentation.FileFormat.PDF);
                    filesStreams.Add(ms2);

                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    Workbook xls = new Workbook();
                    xls.LoadFromFile(item.ToString());
                    xls.SaveToStream(ms3, Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
                    filesStreams.Add(ms3);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
        string outputFile = "result.pdf";
        PdfDocumentBase result = PdfDocument.MergeFiles(filesStreams.ToArray());
        result.Save(outputFile, Spire.Pdf.FileFormat.PDF);
        ms1.Close();
        ms2.Close();
        ms3.Close();            
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error ` result.Save(outputFile, Spire.Pdf.FileFormat.PDF);` here is the error i get `CS0012  C# The type 'HttpContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

Comment: Add reference of System.Web library by right clicking the project in Solution Explorer window and then clicking Add Reference option from the context menu.

The above action will open up the Add Reference Dialog and from the .Net Tab, you need to choose System.Web library and click OK. If my answer helps, please mark it as answer. Thank you.